# SAS rename table with name with blanks

Tags: sas, rename

I have 2 tables:retail with my data and col_dic as a dictionary for column names. In col_dic there are 2 columns - eng_name and eng_name_bl.

So th code is:

```
data _null_;
    set col_dic end = last;
    if _n_ eq 1 then call execute('proc datasets nolist lib=work; modify retail; rename');
    call execute(catx('=', eng_name,eng_name_bl));
    if last then call execute(';quit;');
run;
```

After executing log gives a mistake, where it wants '=' after blank in new column name.
How can i avoid it?

---

Example that does work:

```
data col_dic;
  length eng_name eng_name_bl $20;
  eng_name = 'AGE';
  eng_name_bl = 'AGE_FIX';
  output;
  eng_name = 'HEIGHT';
  eng_name_bl = 'HEIGHT_FIX';
  output;
run;

data class;
  set sashelp.class;
run;


data _null_;
    set col_dic end = last;
    if _n_ eq 1 then call execute('proc datasets nolist lib=work; modify class; rename');
    call execute(catx('=', eng_name,eng_name_bl));
    if last then call execute(';quit;');
run;
```

Comment: It seemed that you did not use single quotation after second call execute. Try this: call execute('catx("=", 'eng_name','eng_name_bl')');

Comment: it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Are you trying to change a table name or a column name? Please provide a [complete reproducible example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that generates the error message.

Comment: Catx is problem. call execute(''||name||'='||eng_name||'');

Comment: @ShenglinChen I think you do not understand the (admittedly poorly phrased) question.  `eng_name` and `eng_name_bl` seem to be variables holding the variable names to be renamed (otherwise, why use call execute).

Comment: @user3013203 You need to provide some example data that fails to work properly.  I compiled an example (I will edit it into the Q) that _does_ work properly.  My feeling is you probably have a row that has `eng_name_bl=' '` or `eng_name=' '`, in which case it will fail, but you need to show that example.  Please modify my example to produce the failure condition.

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't do this. Variable names with spaces in them are pain in the neck.  Why don't you just use the value with spaces in it as the LABEL instead of the NAME?

If you do want to specify a variable name that contains spaces then you need make sure to set

```
option validvarname=any;
```

Then in the code generation step use the `NLITERAL()` function to convert the string with spaces to a valid SAS name literal to avoid the syntax errors.

```
call execute(catx('=', nliteral(eng_name),nliteral(eng_name_bl)));
```

Comment: Thank you, Tom. It hepled, but now i Have a limitation on 32 characters in new names. I need to export it to excel with "user-friendly" names later, will it work if I use labels? is there limitations for label character number?

Comment: Labels can be up to 256 characters. I believe that PROC EXPORT will allow you to use the label as the column headers in the generated Excel file.

Comment: You can use the QUOTE() function to insure that your generated label statement has the labels properly quoted. This is especially important if any of the label values contain `"` characters.